# python sendall not raising connection closed error

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I have the following code, tested with python2.7 and python3.5 , on linux / mac , on distant and local machines:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8080))
s.sendall(b'first')
time.sleep(20)
s.sendall(b'should fail')
```

on the other side I have a "server" running with `netcat -l -p8080`

as soon as I see the `first` , I kill the netcat command

However the `s.sendall` does not raise any exception, why so ?

Edit: note that doing `s.sendall` one more time then rise the exception

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8080))
s.sendall(b'first')
time.sleep(20)
s.sendall(b'should fail')
s.sendall(b'now it really fails')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the client side represented by your python code does not yet know that the server's socket is closed and gone. Think of the TCP connection as two separate channels: one in each direction. The TCP protocol allows each side to close its sending side of the connection at a time of its own choosing. And TCP has no way of indicating to the other side that future sends in the other direction will not be accepted.

In more detail... Ordinary termination of a TCP session involves *each* side sending a packet with the `FIN` flag set. That indicates that the peer sending the `FIN` will not send any more data. It does *not* indicate that the receiver of the `FIN` packet may not send any more data.

So, what happens here is that when you kill `netcat`, a `FIN` packet is sent from the server side to the client (and acknowledged by the network stack on behalf of the client). That closes the server=>client direction of the socket. However, the client=>server direction is still usable as far as the client side knows. Later, when your client attempts to send data, a packet is sent containing the data. Now, the network stack on the server side immediately responds telling the client side that the server is no longer there by sending a `RST` packet. However, your `sendall` function call is long-finished by the time that is received.

So, if your client were to sleep another second (or actually just a small fraction of a second) and then attempt *another* send, that subsequent send *would* raise an exception.

It might be instructive to create a packet capture of the entire session and study it with wireshark. Run this in another window before invoking your python code (then kill with Ctrl-C afterward):

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo -w /tmp/f.pcap port 8080
```

You can also use wireshark to capture it, specifying the same `port 8080` as a capture filter -- or `tcp.port == 8080` as a display filter.

Comment: hmmm yes if I had a 3rd "sleep then sendall" this one fail with broken pipe, so it means if I want to test if a connection is closed, I need to call at least 2 time "sendall" (or send) ?

Comment: a 2nd time should be ok without any sleep (or luck) right ? because the call is blocking , right ?

Comment: Not necessarily without a sleep. The call is "blocking" -- but only until your data is copied into kernel network buffers, it still won't have finished sending and receiving the `RST` packet when the `sendall` call returns. There are several ways to detect that the other side has closed. One is to call `select` with your socket as one of the "read" FDs -- the idea being that when the other side closes, `select` will tell you that the socket became readable (in fact, calling `read`/`recv` after that point will return end-of-file on the socket).