# Python sockets exception handling throws no error in first iteration

Tags: python, syslog

I am trying to write a simple syslog client.

This is working quite well and runs into an exception when the syslog server goes down unexpectedly. The only problem now i discovered while debugging is the following:

When i shut down the syslog server it throws not immediatly an exception when i try to send a message. It only throws an exception after the next iteration while the syslog server is down. 
So basically i will loose one message.

Please see example/steps below:

1.) the syslog server is started, i send the first message "test1" from the for loop, this is successfull.

2.) i shutdown the syslog server, now i send the second message "test2" from the for loop(while debugging). Nothing happens, no exception!

3.) i send the third message "test3", now an exception is thrown.

How is this possible? Why doesn't it throw the exception in the first iteration while the syslog server is down?

```
class Syslog:
  def __init__(self,host="localhost",port=514,facility=Facility.DAEMON):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.facility = facility
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

  def connect(self):
    try:
        self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed setting up connection")


  def send(self, message,level):
    data = "<%d>%s" % (level + self.facility*8, message + "\n")
    try:
        self.socket.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))
    except Exception as e:
        print("send failed")

#if __name__ == '__main__':
syslog1 = Syslog(host='HOSTIPADDRESS-NAME')
syslog1.connect()
messages = ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7"]

for message in messages:
    syslog1.send(message,Level.WARNING)
```

Comment: I think because your port is occupied in the third attempt. Try to refresh it

Comment: i think it is a bit more complicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613006/python-sendall-not-raising-connection-closed-error